# Understanding the error: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a web form project that I started in VS2010 and I have recently upgraded to VS2013.

However I am now getting the above error.
 Searching the web the solution states to add the following key in my web.config file.

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

However why am I getting this error in the first place?
I have several pages that work, but it wasn't until I added my Login.aspx file did I start to get this error.

Am I getting this error because this particular page is using ASP validators?

What I don't like is when I add the above web.config key I get a javascript error:
JavaScript critical error at line 3, column 1 in http://localhost:11111/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error

If I continue on past the error the page does function correctly.

If I can better understand this error maybe it would be more beneficial for me to address this particular page instead of just turning off stuff in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Comments on this post I found in the wild:

[Coding Fusion link](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a-Scri)

Suggest that you can register your jquery script properly in Web Forms by adding this to your page load codebehind:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition { Path = "~/scripts/...", DebugPath = "~/scripts/..." });"
```

This may be preferable to turning off settings in your web config.

Comment: Hmm I must not be implementing it correctly.  I still get that error.

Comment: Never actually tried this myself, so maybe it just doesn't work. Is the `Path` correct for where your jquery is?

Comment: Yes.  I would assume that I could use this code and somehow set it in my master page, but I'm not quite sure how to make that happen since I can't add ScriptManager to the head element.